# How to fix top alignment issue using CSS multi-col layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-multicolumn-layout

I am having issues aligning the top of each column using css multicol.

I have tried adding `margin-top: 0;` to h2 and p tags but that did seem to do it. I have also tried:

```
.col-container > * {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

and:

```
.col-container > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

with no luck.

https://codepen.io/joeymorello/pen/GbeyWB?editors=1100

I have checked it in chrome, firefox, and edge. All showing the top alignment of each column to be off

Comment: Have you tried removing the margin-top of the <ul> element?

Comment: @heatherhtml totally missed that.. it works, thank you